# Good (Sidon) Approximation of "Bumps"

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Given a rational point $p\in S^1$ and a continuous function $f:S^1\rightarrow \mathbb C$, we say that $f$ is an $\epsilon$-bump around $p$ (for some $\epsilon>0$) if $f(p)=1,|f|_{\infty}\leq 1+\epsilon$, and $|f(z)|<\epsilon$ for $|z-p|>\epsilon$.

A set of functions $\mathcal F$ will be called a "bump basis" if for any rational $p\in S^1$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\epsilon'<\epsilon$ such that $\mathcal F$ contains an $\epsilon'$ bump around $p$.

My question is the following. Given a subset $E\subset \mathbb Z$ of integers, determine whether $\mathcal F=\overline{span\{z^k\}_{k\in E}}^{\infty}$ (the closure in the supremum norm) is a bump basis.

More specifically, I want to find such $E$ that will also be a Sidon set, and even more specifically, I want it to be invariant under $n\mapsto 2n$.